# Social Network Analysis - Get the List of InBoundEdges for Directed Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I wish to get the list of inwards edges for a node. `IncidenceList` provides both inwards and outwards list. I can of course filter with `Cases` using the following way. But is there any better way or built-in function for the same?

```
InBoundEdges[graph_, x_] := Cases[IncidenceList[graph, x], _ \[DirectedEdge] x]
```

When I use the `InBoundEdges` function in one of my simulation functions I am getting *MaxFormatDepthExceeded exception*, even for a smaller number of nested operations. I need around *10000 number of iterations*.

Lets take an Example,

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 4 -> 2, 2 -> 6, 1 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 6 -> 4}];
IncidenceList[g, 2]
IncidenceList[g, 2][[All, 1]]
InBoundEdges[g, 2]
```

Now `IncidenceList[g, 2]` gives

```
{1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 4 -> 2, 2 -> 6}
```

but I only need `{1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 2}` which I can get with `InBoundEdges` written above. However it is not an efficient solution.

Comment: You might consider accepting the answer of your former question in order to encourage answers :) To do so click on the [acceptance sign](http://i.imgur.com/6LCFKzH.png).

Comment: Can you provide an example of `graph` and your expected result?

Comment: @Öskå Hope it is not exactly the duplicate of my previous question. Actually, I am very new to Functional programming. So my thinking is more biased toward OOP (java/C#) which I used for last 10 years. Even if it is the duplicate one, please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`EdgeList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EdgeList.html) for this purpose and it's a little faster than your solution:

```
InBoundEdges[graph_, x_] := Cases[IncidenceList[graph, x], _ \[DirectedEdge] x];
inBoundEdges[graph_, x_] := EdgeList[graph, _ \[DirectedEdge] x]
```

working on your basic example:

```
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 4 -> 2, 2 -> 6, 1 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 6 -> 4}];
inBoundEdges[g, 2] === InBoundEdges[g, 2]
```

> True

On a bigger `Graph`:

```
ClearAll@g
g[n_] := Graph[EdgeList@StarGraph[n] /. {x_ <-> y_ :> y -> x}];
(InBoundEdges[g@1000000, 1];) // AbsoluteTiming
(inBoundEdges[g@1000000, 1];) // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {5.892337, Null}
>
> {5.276302, Null}